# dropdown menu is hidden behind the slideshow directly below it

Tags: z-index, hidden, dropdown

The button on my website called "more" has a dropdown box that is hidden behind the slideshow below it.

I have tried the z-index code, but it is not working, because my slideshow cannot be "fixed," "relative," or "absolute," which is a requirement for the z-index to work.

www.luckettpump.com/index.php  (be sure to type the address exactly like that, since luckettpump.com currently goes to the html old version of the website.)

Thank you for your help.

Jennifer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to set z-index for main div only that will be set your menu proper, please check below first-div that is from your site:

```
<div style="background-color:white;z-index: 1002" class="col-sm-1"> 
  <div class="menu_more">
<div class="dropdown open"> 
<button data-toggle="dropdown" type="button" class="btn btn-default dropdown-toggle" aria-expanded="true">More<span class="caret"></span></button>


   <ul role="menu" class="dropdown-menu">
  <li><a href="http://luckettpump.com/gallery/fogrod/1.php" tabindex="-1">FogRod</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://luckettpump.com/gallery/scada/1.php" tabindex="-1">SCADA</a></li>   
  </ul>

  </div>
  </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Hi, That worked! Thank you! I am only having this problem in one other place, but the same code does not seem to work. On the same page (www.luckettpump.com/index.php) there is a button called "index." The dropdown box is also partially hidden, though the part that is showing does reveal the wording on the menu. If there is a way to also unhide this menu from behind the slideshow, that would completely fix my problems with this website. Again, thank you so much.